# Netstat Routing Table

Tags: networking, routing

How does one interpret the routing table that is generated by the `netstat -r` command?

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/docs/linux_network/x-087-2-iface.netstat.html

Comment: If you're wondering about the all-zero entries in the Destination or Gateway columns, have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94018/what-is-the-meaning-of-0-0-0-0-as-a-gateway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean Linux:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.17.184.0     *               255.255.248.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
default         10.17.184.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

The table defines the route to be taken based upon the destination address of a connection.  The Destination and Genmask fields are combined to produce a subnet of addresses to which a rule applies.  On most systems you have a simple routing table like mine, above.  A gateway address of "*" implies that the packets will simply be sent out the interface to reach their target destination.  Rule 1 for example, is for reaching systems in my local LAN.

A default rule is usually displayed at the bottom, which is the router to which the packets are sent if no other rules match.

If you paste your routing table with specific rules that are confusing, I could provide more detail.

Comment: On Macs, it seems the routing table is upside down, that may have been adding to my confusion.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to check mine when I get home.

Comment: Don't rely on the order. It's not first match, but most accurate (most bits in the mask). There's usually an exception that "connected" networks rate above any other routes.